# Is there a way to lazily vectorize a given class?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Before you object: every programmer is lazy. Otherwise you would not program and do everything manually!

---

#### A simple example.

I have a class `Line` which contains everything that is needed to handle a line (like an object created using two vertices/points). This class is actually really complex and for the sake of simplicity, maintainability and clarity I'd like to keep it like this: a class that I feed with two vertices and outputs some difficult results such as the distance between the two points.

#### The problem

Now, the problem is that while I need to keep track of these individual lines, I also want, sometimes, to handle them as a whole. For instance, I would like to calculate the length of a path made of many lines.

#### Current solution and shortcomings

I created a class named `Lines` which also provides a handful of methods for that.

`Lines` is currently a child of `numpy.ndarray` which is not so great:

- the namespace is cluttered by ndarray's methods;
- I'm using `ufunc`s to provide a wrapper within `Lines` around the methods of `Line` but this is tedious to maintain the code in two places like this.

#### Question

So, how would you guys do to "vectorize" the `Line` class efficiently while keeping track of the individual lines?

I could put everything in `Lines` and consider `Line` as a special case, I tried, but it really hurts clarity and make all the referencing of individual lines quite difficult to implement and maintain.

---

#### Code example

```
import numpy as np
class Line:
    def __init__ (self, input_points):
        assert len(np.array(input_points).squeeze()) == 2
        self._points = np.array(input_points)

    def get_distance(self):
        return np.sqrt(((self._points[0]-self._points[1])**2).sum())

from itertools import combinations
class Lines(np.ndarray):

   _get_dists = np.frompyfunc(Line.get_distance, 1, 1)

   def __new__(cls, data):
       comb = [Line(el) for el in combinations(data, 2)]
       obj = np.asarray(comb).view(cls)
       obj = obj.squeeze()
       return obj

   def get_all_distances(self):
       return self._get_dists(self)
```

Comment: Is `Lines` just a general set of `Line`s, or do they relate to each other in some way? Also, can you give a specific example of a method you'd like to "vectorize"?

Comment: Currently, all the data is loaded and split inside `Lines` to create a set of `Line` objects. These objects are the only data that `Lines` keeps for the moment. I'm currently working on a way to keep *all* the data as a numpy array in memory. `Lines` would access this array directly while references to subparts of this arrays would be passed to `Line` instances.

Comment: It would really, really help to have some code (not your whole program, just a small, runnable sample) instead of having to guess…

Comment: how is this distance? `(self._points[0] + self._points[1])/2`

Comment: Oh, come on, I had to make that up in a couple of minutes and at first I wanted to speak about midpoint.

Comment: @Gael: Well, you got halfway there. ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you want Lines to be able to *use* `ndarray` methods, but not have its public namespace cluttered with those methods, use delegation instead of inheritance. In other words, instead of this:

```
class Lines(np.ndarray):
    def __init__(self, whatever):
        super().__init__(stuff)
    def dostuff(self, thingies):
        np.do_thingy(self.stuff(spam))
        return self.spam(eggs)
```

… do this:

```
class Lines(object):
    def __init__(self, whatever):
        self.lines = np.array(stuff)
    def dostuff(self, thingies):
        np.do_thingy(self.lines.stuff(spam))
        return self.lines.spam(eggs)
```

---

Meanwhile, it sounds like you have a set of `Line` methods that you want ufuncify in `Lines`, and you're sick of repeating yourself. So do that dynamically. Here's a trivial example to give you the idea:

```
for name in 'bam', 'biff', 'pow', 'kazaam':
    func = getattr(Line, name)
    ufunc = np.frompyfunc(func, 1, 1)
    setattr(Lines, name, ufunc)
```

Comment: ive never heard this called "delegation" before.. but I immediately knew what you meant.. +1!

Comment: @qwwqwwq: I people have gradually stopped using this name because the same word has too many other meanings, but I don't know of any other name. In particular, explicitly building bound methods in .NET languages and ObjC is called "delegation". At least in C++ it means a specific subset of the original meaning (their clumsy equivalent of what Python does in a 3-line `__getattr__`).

Comment: Not bad. And this way, I can even slightly alter the name of the method in the wrapper.

Comment: @Gael: One minor thing to keep in mind: If you store a method under a new name, you usually want to set its `__name__` attribute as well, or your error tracebacks, etc. can get confusing. See [`functools.wraps`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) (and the link to the source at the top of the docs, since it's intended to serve as example code too) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

[After writing this answer I saw @abarnert gave an answer along the same lines, but this answer looks different, so I post it, in case it helps]

You can explicitly wrap each method and property you'd need (using one *generic* wrapping function for methods, and one for properties), and manually assign the wrapped result to the `Lines` class:

```
class Line(object):
    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2
    def diff(self):
        return self.p2 - self.p1
    @property
    def point1(self):
        return self.p1

class Lines(object):
    def __init__(self, lines):
        self._lines = np.array(lines, dtype = object)

def _wrapped_method(mname):
    def f(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return np.array([ getattr(line, mname)(*args, **kwargs) for line in self._lines ])
    return f

def _wrapped_property(pname):
    def f(self):
        return np.array([ getattr(line, pname) for line in self._lines ])
    return property(f)

wrapped_methods = ( 'diff', )
for mname in wrapped_methods:
    setattr(Lines, mname, _wrapped_method(mname))

wrapped_properties = ( 'point1', )
for pname in wrapped_properties:
    setattr(Lines, pname, _wrapped_property(pname))

lines = Lines([ Line(3,5) ])  # 3,5 are not really points, but good enough for demonstration
print '%r' % lines.diff()
# array([2])
print '%r' % lines.point1
# array([3])
```

Comment: Not bad. As with the other answer, this gives me some ideas to explore.